# Executing unix commands in ObjC

Tags: objective-c, unix, command

How to write a program for executing the 'ls' command in ObjC ?
 Any API available ?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`NSTask`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSTask_Class/Reference/Reference.html) is your friend if speed isn't necessary. If it is, use the native system calls.

---

If you're only concerned about listing the contents of a directory, read the [Guide about Low-Level File Management](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/LowLevelFileMgmt/Introduction.html). Especially [Listing the Contents of a Directory](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/LowLevelFileMgmt/Articles/EnumADir.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000783-BAJFBAAH) could be interesting.$

If that still isn't fast enough, use the C API. See this question: [How do you get a directory listing in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12489/how-do-you-get-a-directory-listing-in-c).

Answer (score 3):

As far as I'm aware, Objective C is built on C so you should have access to all the standard UNIXy capabilities, among them:

- `system()`.
- `fork()`.
- `exec()` family.
- `popen()`.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget about [`posix_spawn()`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/posix_spawn.2.html), for when you need to exert dictatorial-level control over your sub-processes.

Of course, if you're just looking to do file system management and introspection from Cocoa proper, look no further than [`NSFileManager`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: i want to execute and cache all the system calls and unix commands as we do in the terminal.