# File count in a directory using C++

Tags: c++

How do I get the total number of files in a directory by using C++ standard library?

Comment: Directory operation is relative to the OS you're on, unfortunately. So post with what OS you're trying, then perhaps we can better help you.

Comment: Cross platform code to work on both Windows and Linux.
I'm using mingw, gcc and msvc along with wxWidgets library, using boost but not linking to its libraries, only including headers.

fstat and _stat functions we have in #include <sys/stat.h>.
to get file details. Do we have similar support for getting directory details?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can't. The closest you are going to be able to get is to use something like [Boost.Filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm)

EDIT: It is possible with C++17 using the STL's [filesystem](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/directory_iterator) library

Comment: After which it's trivial: `int count = std::difference(directory_iterator(dir_path), directory_iterator());`

Comment: @MSalters, I can't find any reference to `std::difference`. Are you sure you didn't mean `std::distance`? Also, you'll need a `static_cast<int>` to coerce `directory_iterator::difference_type` to `int`.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid linking to Boost libraries and use only headers for algorithms.

Comment: do we have a way to avoid linking to Boost filesystem library and still get the support for this?

Comment: @Nathan: of course.  @harik: doesn't work; the code you need is in the Boost library.

Answer (score 22):

If you don't exclude the basically always available C standard library, you can use that one.
Because it's available everywhere anyways, unlike boost, it's a pretty usable option!

An example is given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12489/how-do-you-get-a-directory-listing-in-c).

And here:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <dirent.h>

int main (void)
{
  DIR *dp;
  int i = 0;
  struct dirent *ep;     
  dp = opendir ("./");

  if (dp != NULL)
  {
    while (ep = readdir (dp))
      i++;

    (void) closedir (dp);
  }
  else
    perror ("Couldn't open the directory");

  printf("There's %d files in the current directory.\n", i);

  return 0;
}
```

And sure enough

```
 > $ ls -a | wc -l
138
 > $ ./count
There's 138 files in the current directory.
```

This isn't C++ at all, but it is available on most, if not all, operating systems, and will work in C++ regardless.

**UPDATE:** I'll correct my previous statement about this being part of the C standard library - it's not. But you can carry this concept to other operating systems, because they all have their ways of dealing with files without having to grab out additional libraries.

**EDIT:** : Added initialization of i

Comment: -1: The C standard library provides no way to enumerate a directory either.

Comment: That's a stupid down vote. Of course you can count files using the C standard lib. Take the example I included in my post - instead of calling a "puts ..." inside the while used to iterate over every file, just do "i++" and declare an "int i" somewhere above. There is of course no "directory_get_file_count" function, but that isn't the point. The point is, you CAN use it to get your desired result, namely the amount of files in a folder. The hell, let me edit my original answer with a spoon fed answer, sec

Comment: As for the POSIX part of readdir, that's true, but in windows you have  similar functions that I could not test here because I haven't used windows in ages. But the point is: this works in C++, this works in C, you don't need to install special library support and that's what the OP probably wanted.

Comment: @LukeN: POSIX **is** "special library support". Windows does not have a `<sys/types.h>` nor does it have a `<dirent.h>`. POSIX is not the C standard library, and your assertion that it is is wrong.

Comment: POSIX yay or nay left aside, one would not simply transfer a C program like this from one operating system to another anyways - all major operating systems have their ways to deal with files and directories. THIS was the Linux example, windows deal with it another way, probably windows.h or something, one can just write some "#ifdef" to handle that and be happy. I'll correct my statement about it being standard C, and just say that those functions will be available wherever such a program would typically run. The asker does not have to install a special library, and that's what counts for me!

Comment: I tend to take things like this to personal, sorry about that. Of course you're right. But I think this is what the poster wanted. Listing files without separatly installing libraries like boost. :)

Comment: Basically you've now arrived at the comment Daniel made initially: "just use the native OS functions, not a (standard) library".

Comment: Basically, but I supplied examples, too!

Comment: This solution will not work for me on Windows. I may have to use Boost like libraries for getting required support across platforms.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but consider initializing `i` to 0. The code as is invokes undefined behavior. I tried editing it myself but SO requires at least 6 characters of change for an edit (at least with my rep). One of their dumbest rules...

Answer (score 7):

As of C++17 it can be done with STL:

```
auto dirIter = std::filesystem::directory_iterator("directory_path");

int fileCount = std::count_if(
    begin(dirIter),
    end(dirIter),
    [](auto& entry) { return entry.is_regular_file(); }
);
```

A simple for-loop works, too:

```
auto dirIter = std::filesystem::directory_iterator("directory_path");
int fileCount = 0;

for (auto& entry : dirIter)
{
    if (entry.is_regular_file())
    {
        ++fileCount;
    }
}
```

See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/directory_iterator

Comment: To confirm, is `is_regular_file()` your custom function or an in-built C++ one? Because I'm getting an error for that: `error: ‘const class std::experimental::filesystem::v1::__cxx11::directory_entry’ has no member named ‘is_regular_file’
             if (entry.is_regular_file()) {
                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~`

Comment: @Milan : `entry.is_regular_file()` should be `is_regular_file(entry.path())` which is a `std:filesystem` function.

Answer (score 6):

An old question, but since it appears first on Google search, I thought to add my answer since I had a need for something like that.

```
int findNumberOfFilesInDirectory(std::string& path)
{
    int counter = 0;
    WIN32_FIND_DATA ffd;
    HANDLE hFind = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;

    // Start iterating over the files in the path directory.
    hFind = ::FindFirstFileA (path.c_str(), &ffd);
    if (hFind != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        do // Managed to locate and create an handle to that folder.
        { 
            counter++;
        } while (::FindNextFile(hFind, &ffd) == TRUE);
        ::FindClose(hFind);
    } else {
        printf("Failed to find path: %s", path.c_str());
    }

    return counter;
}
```

Comment: To get the number of files in folder *path* you'll have to append path with "\\*" and to eliminate "." and ".." before incrementing counter by checking ffd.cFileName

Answer (score 3):

If they are well named, sorted, and have the same extension, you could simply do count them with standard C++ library.

Assume the file names are like "img_0.jpg..img_10000.jpg..img_n.jpg",
Just check if they are in the folder or not.

```
int Trainer::fileCounter(string dir, string prefix, string extension)
{
    int returnedCount = 0;
    int possibleMax = 5000000; //some number you can expect.

    for (int istarter = 0; istarter < possibleMax; istarter++){
        string fileName = "";
        fileName.append(dir);
        fileName.append(prefix);
        fileName.append(to_string(istarter));
        fileName.append(extension);
        bool status = FileExistenceCheck(fileName);

        returnedCount = istarter;

        if (!status)
            break;
    }

    return returnedCount;
}

bool Trainer::FileExistenceCheck(const std::string& name) {
    struct stat buffer;
    return (stat(name.c_str(), &buffer) == 0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use a native API or framework.

Answer (score 0):

```
auto it = std::filesystem::directory_iterator{"myDir"}; // or `recursive_directory_iterator`
```

count everything:

```
std::distance(it, {});
```

count only regular files:

```
std::count_if(it, {}, [](auto& x){return x.is_regular_file(); });
```

(do not reuse the iterator after it has been modified, or be careful.)