# Directory listing in C on Windows

Tags: c, windows, directory-listing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you get a directory listing in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12489/how-do-you-get-a-directory-listing-in-c)
>   [Listing directory contents using C and Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2314542/listing-directory-contents-using-c-and-windows)

How do you write a program which lists the directories recursively just like `dir /s C:\` in the command prompt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call the Windows API `FindFirstFile` and `FindNextFile` to iterate in a directory and do it recursively on subdirectories. See the [Example on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365200%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

To list file contents you can search a directory with these APIs:

- [FindFirstFileEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364419%28VS.85%29.aspx),
- [FindNextFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364428%28VS.85%29.aspx) and
- [FindClose](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364413%28VS.85%29.aspx).

You'll need to `#include <windows.h>`, that'll get you access to the Windows API. They're C functions and so compatible with C++. If you want "specifically C++", try searching for listing directories using MFC.